# How does this binary tree traversal algorithm work?

Tags: java, binary-tree, traversal

So I'm given the algorithm

```java
void traverse(Node node) {
    if (node != null) {
        traverse(node.leftChild);
        System.out.println(node.name);
        traverse(node.rightChild);
    }
}
```

I don't understand how this works. So if I'm at a point where the input is null, what happens?
Assuming that we print the null node's parent (I don't know how you get there) and continue on, let's say we've covered nodes deep into a tree, how do we climb back up the tree? Where in this algorithm can we continuously jump to parent nodes as needed?

Comment: does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49080353) answer your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To understand this you need to understand recursion first. Here for every node as parent we do same thing for left child then for the right child. and print the parent name after traverse left side.

When node is null we don't do anything, so no child is called

```
void traverse(Node node) {
    if(node!=null) {
        traverse(node.leftChild);
        System.out.println(node.name);
        traverse(node.rightChild);
    }
}
```

Example:

```
parent and childs
1 -> 2,3
2 -> 4,5
3 -> 6,7
```

So here traverse(1) called as root first.

```
traverse(1) -> traverse(2) // left
               traverse(3) // right

traverse(2) -> traverse(4) // left
               traverse(5) // right

traverse(3) -> traverse(6) // left
               traverse(7) // right

traverse(4) -> nothing called
traverse(5) -> nothing called
traverse(6) -> nothing called
traverse(7) -> nothing called
```

Now exact the order it called

```
traverse(1) -> traverse(2) // left
                  traverse(2) -> traverse(4) // left
                                     traverse(4) -> nothing called
                                 traverse(5) // right
                                     traverse(5) -> nothing called
               traverse(3) // right
                  traverse(3) -> traverse(6) // left
                                      traverse(6) -> nothing called
                                 traverse(7) // right
                                      traverse(7) -> nothing called
```

Comment: Thank you! My misunderstanding was that calling the function recursively somehow erased the later functions (print and traverse(right)) from the original call, but they're really called later on.

Comment: If it solved your understanding problem then try to accept it.